# 'Could not load file or assembly' when I want to add Add Identity system in .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, filenotfoundexception, .net-6.0

I'm using .NET 6 RC2.
When I was used .NET 5 everything was fine but now that I use .NET 6
when I want to Add Identity I get this error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

And I can't enter this method:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddIdentityOptions(
    this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddIdentity<User, Role>();

    return services;
}
```

When I call this method in program.cs (.NET 6 doesn't have startup.cs) and Ioc container, I can't enter to this method at all and get above error.
Anybody knows how can I fix it ?

Comment: Can you please post [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) somewhere, for example github?

Comment: Here you are sir I get error of above in this line : https://github.com/VahidN/DNTIdentity/blob/master/src/ASPNETCoreIdentitySample.IocConfig/IdentityServicesRegistry.cs#L17