# How to install preview or RC package via Nuget in visual?

Tags: nuget, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I'm using NET6 RC. how can I install RC or preview package in Nuget window in visual studio 2022 preview ? because for now Nuget window in visual studio 2022 preview just show me stable version of the packages.
for example :

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.0-rc.2.21480.5" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check ["Include prerelease" box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/prerelease-packages#installing-and-updating-pre-release-packages) in the Manage NuGet Packages UI:

[image]

Comment: Sir can you help me about this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69824834